# Is there a single word for 'in keeping with the times'?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example: 'The book is racist, in keeping with the time it was written.'

Answer (score 2):

For its *generation*.

In Genesis it is said of Noah that he was a righteous man, blameless among the people *of his time*. This is a slightly modernized version of;

Noah was a righteous man, blameless *in his generation*.

The point made in the original text is that for that *generation* Noah had always done the right thing, unlike so many. The text is admitting that things change over time and people have to deal with the rules and context they find themselves in.

The only thing that can be considered as racist in any time is a text that dutifully explains why races [definition please] are different and one is (usually clearly) better than another. What people commonly refer to as racist texts are those that display a bias (perceived or otherwise) that is clear by modern lights but may not have been quite so when they were current, in their own *generation*

Comment: The Bible is a good example - it is filled with references to inferior races. But, of course, those are attitudes that were prevalent at that time.

Comment: @Greybeard; I don't think there are any ancient texts that do not try to keep score of such things. I may be biased myself since I mostly stick to Joseph Campbell's histories of mythology.

Answer (score 0):

'The book is racist, contemporaneous with the time it was written.'

OED

**contemporaneous** 1. Existing at or occurring during the same period of time; belonging to or originating in the same time or period.

a. With *with*, or occasionally *to*.

1923   Amer. Jrnl. Philol. 44 173   *It was taken for granted that the composition of this work was practically contemporaneous with the events narrated.*

*PS, To convey your intended meaning, it is not the **book** that is racist - the **contents of the book** are racist.*

Comment: Contemporaneous only says that the two happen at the same time. The printing and marketing are also contemporaneous. What is being sought is a word to explain that the *ideas* were current at that time. Not just the trivial circumstances surrounding the events.

Answer (score -1):

I would say "consistent".

According to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/consistent):

- Acting or done in the same way over time, especially so as to be fair or accurate.